# How to error Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex

Tags: google-bigquery

How this error occurs "Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex" in google BigQuery

[image]

Comment: Have you fixed this ? I have an insert query with 10K of rows and I am getting this .

Comment: I'm running into the same issue and I'm unsure if requesting a quota increase fixes the problem. In my case, I have a lot of recursive table in a single query with many aggregations and stuff. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Would you mind posting the entire query. I suspect you have more than 16 CTE in the query and hence the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I had multiple views (or if they are CTEs in your case) I was referencing.To fix the issue, I needed to convert the views (or CTEs) to Tables. Then I referenced the Tables in my original query that was giving me this error. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql same here to reduce query is to complex

SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(week_1_cohort)*100,  SUM(IF(row_number >= 1, week_0_cohort, 0))) as week_1_cohort

Answer (score 0):

that means probably that or you slim the amount of memory required by your query, or you  need to increase your limits, whose explanation you find at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas)