# Snapshot fails because of "Resources exceeded during query execution"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, snapshot, dbt

At the end of my dbt pipeline that transform my data in a bigquery database I have scheduled some basic snapshots. This snap enables me to picture a calendar table with sales forecast for each day. It's quite basic and not complexe.

Never had any issue with all my other snap before but with that one I have the following error :

```
"Database Error in snapshot sales_forecasts_snapshot (snapshots/sales_forecasts_snapshot.sql)
07:55:51    Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex."
```

Here is the code :

```
'''{% snapshot sales_forecasts_snapshot %}
{{
config(
  target_database='baobab-304613',
  target_schema='snapshots',
  unique_key='calendar_day',
  strategy='timestamp',
  updated_at='updated_at',
)
}}

select
 calendar_day                                                   AS calendar_day
,CAST(total_forecast_sales_paying_members AS NUMERIC)           AS total_forecast_sales_paying_members
,CAST(forecast_nb_paying_members AS NUMERIC)                    AS forecast_nb_paying_members
,CAST(forecast_sales_per_paying_member AS NUMERIC)              AS forecast_sales_per_paying_member

,CAST(total_forecast_sales_free_members AS NUMERIC)             AS total_forecast_sales_free_members
,CAST(forecast_nb_free_members AS NUMERIC)                      AS forecast_nb_free_members
,CAST(forecast_sales_per_free_member AS NUMERIC)                AS forecast_sales_per_free_member

,CAST(total_forecast_sales_free_trialer AS NUMERIC)             AS total_forecast_sales_free_trialer
,CAST(forecast_nb_free_trialers AS NUMERIC)                     AS forecast_nb_free_trialers
,CAST(forecast_sales_per_free_trialer AS NUMERIC)               AS forecast_sales_per_free_trialer

,CAST(total_forecast_sales_active_customer_90_days AS NUMERIC)  AS total_forecast_sales_active_customer_90_days
,CAST(forecast_sales_per_active_customer_90_days AS NUMERIC)    AS forecast_sales_per_active_customer_90_days
,CAST(forecast_nb_active_customers_90_days AS NUMERIC)          AS forecast_nb_active_customers_90_days

,updated_at                                                     AS updated_at --this date is the current_date (the date of the day --> the idea is to capture every day the new forecasts) 

from {{ ref('sales_forecasts') }}

{% endsnapshot %}'''
```

This snapshot is based on a view which runs without any issue.
This snapshot is performed with dbt in a bigquery database. When I create the snapshot, it runs perfectly well the first time it runs but then fail at the second launch.
What surprises me is also that even if my pipeline fails because of that, it seems like it still run as I have fresh data in my database.

Comment: That is a database error, not an error on the dbt side. Refer to this answered question, which treats the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870985/how-to-error-resources-exceeded-during-query-execution-not-enough-resources-for

Comment: I have already read that one but my issue is quite different as I'm only inserting less than 1 000 rows without any operation or any function used. I don't get why it's "too heavy"

Comment: I believe this error has nothing to do with the amount of rows you insert, but with the complexity of the query itself. See here: https://docs.holistics.io/faqs/bigquery-too-many-subqueries-query-too-complex

Comment: I agree but there is no complexity at all : no join / not sort / no calculations --> it's a simple snapshot

Comment: I also tried with a "select *" statement in the snap but it didn't work all the same. That's why I tried to reduce the number of columns. I did cast them "AS Numeric" also to be sure about the data format would not be an issue.

Comment: Is the model that you are `ref` from "sales_forecasts" a view or table?

Comment: Yeah its probably that sales_forecasts has nested views too -- I think there is effectively a top line of how many views you can nest.

Comment: The model was a table. I found a solution but finally didn't find the reason why it was not working. The solution was to create an intermediate table between the initial table and the snap with only the few columns I wanted to snap. There were 20 columns in the initial table and I created a simple table like 'Select column 1, column2 etc.... from sales_forecast" and make a snap from this table. The initial table didn't have any nested data so I really don't get why it was not working